# How to force entire animation in :hover:after with css3

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is a simple animation in hover

https://codepen.io/riccardomarconato/pen/EQZJEb

```css
body{
  background-color: black;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.underlineFromLeft {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.underlineFromLeft:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  bottom: -2px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 40px;
  transition-property: width;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.underlineFromLeft:hover:after {
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1><a class="underlineFromLeft" href="">Hover me</a></h1>
```

Works great, but only if you don't leave the mouseover before the animations ends. I tried to figure out with the following js but is not working.

```
$(".underlineFromLeft").bind("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd animationEnd", function(){
  $(this).removeClass("underlineFromLeftAnimate:after")
})

$(".underlineFromLeft").hover(function(){
  $(this).addClass("underlineFromLeftAnimate:after");
})
```

```js
$(".underlineFromLeft").bind("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd animationEnd", function() {
  $(this).removeClass("underlineFromLeftAnimate:after")
})

$(".underlineFromLeft").hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass("underlineFromLeftAnimate:after");
})
```

```css
body{
  background-color: black;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.underlineFromLeft {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.underlineFromLeft:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  bottom: -2px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 40px;
  transition-property: width;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.underlineFromLeft:hover:after {
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1><a class="underlineFromLeft" href="">Hover me</a></h1>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Don't use hover in CSS but start an animation in jQuery on `.hover()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Codepen fork](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VQPOaJ)

---

Change your CSS, removing the `:hover` pseudoclass with a classname, like so

```
.underlineFromLeft.hovered:after {
   left: 0;
   right: auto;
   width: 100%;
}
```

and then change your JS: note that the event you're looking for is `transitionend` (and not `animationend` since you're triggering a CSS transition)

```
$(".underlineFromLeft")
   .on("transitionend", function(){
       this.classList.remove("hovered")
   })
   .on('mouseenter', function() {
       this.classList.add("hovered");
   })
```